# how can i change load css with user in asp razor

Tags: css, asp.net, razor

hi i wanna my users can change the theme in index page i try this code and it works fine with form select and submit botton but its not user friendly how can i do like when the user chose x the css files for x loads and if selected y styles the y css loads how can do that without dosent need to click on submit botton 
the currnet code is in razor layout.csthml

```
 var totalMessage = "";

    if (IsPost)
    {
        var num = Request["number"];

        if (num.AsInt() == 1)
        {
            totalMessage = "dark mode";


            @Styles.Render("~/Styles/defaultdark.css")
            @Styles.Render("~/Styles/regaldark.css")
            @Styles.Render("~/Styles/globaldark.css")




        }
        if (num.AsInt() == 2)
        {
            totalMessage = "white mode";
            @Styles.Render("~/Styles/1/defaultwhite.css")
            @Styles.Render("~/Styles/1/regalwhite.css")
            @Styles.Render("~/Styles/1/globalwhite.css")


        }
```

the form html code i use

```
    <form action="" method="post">
        <p>
            <select name="number">
                <option value="">dear user select your favorit theme</option>
                <option value="1">dark mode</option>
                <option value="2">white mode</option>

            </select>

        </p>

        <p><input type="submit" value=" Add "></p>
    </form>
    <p>@totalMessage</p>
```

and every thing is working but its not user firendly the user must select the theme and after click on submit button but i wanna change the code work with out clicking on submit button just the theme got select the code works

Answer (score 0):

You could look into adding a onchange event on the select

```
    <form action="" method="post">
        <p>
            <select name="number" onchange="themeChange()">
                <option value="">dear user select your favorit theme</option>
                <option value="1">dark mode</option>
                <option value="2">white mode</option>

            </select>

        </p>

        <p><input type="submit" id="submit" value=" Add "></p>
    </form>
    <p>@totalMessage</p>

    <script>
        function themeChange() {
            document.getElementById("submit").click()
        }
    </script>
```